# looking for Java GUI components / ideas for syntax highlighting

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, syntax-highlighting, xquery

I'm not committed to any particular GUI tookit or anything - just needs to be Java based. I want to do simple syntax highlighting ( XML and XQuery ) inside editable text areas.

My only candidate so far is Swing's JTextPane, as it supports seems to support the styling of text, but I have no idea how to implement it in this context.

If a particular toolkit has something like this out of the box, that would be awesome, but I'm open to doing this by hand if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSyntaxPane handles XML and can be extended

http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/wiki/Using

Or, it should be possible to extract the NetBeans editor, but that would probably be more work...

[edit] btw, I got the XML info from [here](http://saveabend.blogspot.com/2008/06/jsyntaxpane-is-born.html)...  it doesn't seem to mention it on the google code pages...

Answer (score 1):

Jide software has a [Syntax Highligher](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/editor.htm) component. It is still in beta, but I think it supposed XML. I haven't used it myself, so I don't know how well it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check out Ostermiller's Syntax Highlighter.

Here's a [simple code editor demo](http://ostermiller.org/syntax/editor.html)

It still uses JTextPane though.